# Phonegap Android plugin package name the same

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, package-name

I found that I coundn't install 2 different phonegap projects in my device at the same time when they have the same plugin added.

When I add plugins to my phonegap project, the android project will create the corresponding packages such as `org.apache.cordova.device`. So two projects would have the same packages with name `org.apache.cordova.device` which is not allowed in Android development because package names must be unique.

Any solutions to change the package name of a plugin in an Android project?

Comment: com.apache.cordova.device is the package name of the plugin and has nothing to do with the package name of your app. It's more likelly you forgot the package name parameter when you created your projects.

Comment: After I import the project into eclipse, I can find under my src folder of both projects, there is a 'org.apache.cordova.device' package. Is it a problem?

Comment: no package names of libraries used inside the app is not the same as the app's package name. To see your app's package name, look at the second line of config.xml or androidmanifest.xml